# Who gets title if you sell a frame and an engine separately

Tags: engine, motorcycle, frame

I have a POS (Piece of S**t) salvage motorcycle I purchased cheap for a purpose which has now passed. I'm ready to get rid of it and there's a guy down the street that mentioned possibly wanting to buy the engine, but only the engine.

Now I know that the frame and the engine both have VIN numbers ... if I sell just the engine, do I give him the title or do I keep the title for when I sell the frame?  Or do I need to get a duplicate title and give him a title and whomever I sell the frame to a title as well?

My question is in regard to whatever would be the proper course of action in relation to California Dept of Motor Vehicle law.

Comment: In the states the title stays with the frame.

Answer (score 3):

In the uk - the titles go with the frame. The engine has its own number but that can be updated by writing to the relevant authority when you do an engine swap.

Answer (score 3):

The engine is a sub-component of the vehicle, just like a transmission.

Think about if you took the vehicle to the shop with a blown engine. You have the engine replaced. The bike is still yours. The title still remains with you (or the bank if they own it). You could strip *everything* off the frame and you'd still retain the title with the frame.